# add data to a listView from another activity kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to this area, I am having problems with the following example.

[image]

I want to add the product data when the ImageButton is clicked to my Product Activity, to the other order detail activity.

**this is my my eclient class**

```
data class epedidos (

var cod_producto: String,
var nom_producto: String,
var cantidad_producto : Int,
var total_apagar : Float


    ){}
```

****This is my ListAdapter.kt adapter****

```
class ListAdapter (var mCtx: Context, var resource:Int, var  items:ArrayList<epedidos>)
: ArrayAdapter<epedidos>(mCtx,resource,items) {

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {

    val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx)

    val view: View = layoutInflater.inflate(resource, null)

   // val imageView: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.img_productos)
    val textpenomproduct: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtpe_nom_product)
    val textpecodproduc: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtpe_cod_produc)
    val textpe_monto: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtpe_Monto)
    val textpecantidad: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtpe_cantidad)

    var myItems: epedidos = items[position]

    textpecodproduc.text = myItems.cod_producto
    textpenomproduct.text = myItems.nom_producto
    textpecantidad.text = myItems.cantidad_producto.toString()
    textpe_monto.text = myItems.total_apagar.toString()
    return view
}}
```

**From my activity product_detail.kt in my event**

```
override fun onClick(p0: View?) {

    when (p0?.id) {

        R.id.imgNuevoPedido -> {

            val intent = Intent(this@DetalleProducto, DetallePedido::class.java)

            val var_acodproducto = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtdetcodproducto)
            val var_detanomproducto = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtdetnomproducto)
            val var_detamarcaproducto = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtdetmarca)
            val var_detalineaproducto = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtdetlinea)
            val var_detaprecioproducto = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtdetprecioproduct)


            val cod_producto = intent.getStringExtra("codproducto")
            val nom_producto = intent.getStringExtra("nombreproducto")
            val marca_producto = intent.getStringExtra("marca")
            val linea_producto = intent.getStringExtra("linea")
            val precio_producto = intent.getStringExtra("precio")
            var_acodproducto.setText(cod_producto)
            var_detanomproducto.setText(nom_producto)
            var_detamarcaproducto.setText(marca_producto)
            var_detalineaproducto.setText(linea_producto)
            var_detaprecioproducto.setText(precio_producto)


            startActivity(intent)

        }


    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to get the data that is sent from the product_detail activity and that is added to my list in my Order_Detail activity

Any idea or reference.

Thanks.

Comment: If you really want to do this with two separate Activities, you need to to launch the second Activity using `startActivityForResult` or by using [Activity result contracts](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result). But generally, the recommendation is to use a single Activity for your whole app and use Fragments to represent the different screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to pass the data from `DetalleProducto` activity to `DetallePedido` activity right?

What you can do is pass the information as Intent Extras, embedded into the intent you use to start `DetallePedido`.

It should look pretty much like what you are already doing, but instead of using `getStringExtra` try `intent.putExtra(...)`.

You should use the `getExtra` functions in the receiving activity as follows:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // ...
    val codProd: String? = intent.getStringExtra("codproducto")
    // ...
```

Furthermore, you can make your `epedido` class `Parcelable` and you can just toss it directly into the extras and receive it on the other side.

Check this link for more details: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles

Comment: It is true I want to pass the data from product_detail to order_detail, how can I fill or add that data to the listview?

Comment: It is true that I should use the getExtra in the receiver but I have the doubt in how to add it to the listview using the order class, I understand that I must create an arraylist

Comment: For that part, there is a simple recipe, see it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview In a nutshell, use a `RecyclerView` and define an Adapter class, which connects your data to the list item view (XML defined). The Adapter receives a collection of your data, and is set to the `RecyclerView`.